# How to hide a dropdown menu in html/javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to Javascript and  trying to create a dropdown menu that hides when a user clicks on another spot on the screen. My code is shown below, why doesn't it work?

```
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
```

Comment: You might start with checking your syntax. There is not one control structure decently closed. Where are your end braces `}`?

Comment: could you add your html and css code?

Answer (score 0):

`event.target` returns the element, if you want to retrieve the elements class name use `.className` , `event.target.className`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target

replace `!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')`

with `event.target.className!= 'dropbtn'`

**UPDATE**
building on @charlietfl's comment add this function to check for ancestor class
and use `if(checkClass (event.tagent, 'dropbtn') === false)` instead

```
function checkClass (el, cls) {
    if(el.classList.contains(cls)) return true;
    return typeof el.parentElement !== null ? checkClass (el.parentElement, cls) : false; 
}
```

**UPDATE:** maybe look into using the blur event https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/blur

Comment: Need to walk up from target and check parents also

Comment: in his case he is only interested to find out that the target isn't the button...

Comment: suppose it looked like `<a class="dropbtn"><span class="icon"></span></a>`. Target wouldn't be that class if click on icon

Comment: Yeah...that's a nice little dom walker function there. People tend to forget that target can be a descendant of what they want to check

Answer (score 0):

```
//first a mod of WalksAway's `checkClass()`
function checkClass(el, cls) {
    return !!el && (el.classList.contains(cls) || checkClass(el.parentElement, cls));
}

//or with a loop:
function checkClass(el, cls) {
    while(el){
        if(el.classList.contains(cls)) return true;
        el = el.parentElement;
    }
    return false;
}
```

and a modification of your code:

```
//a handy little utility-function:
function $$(selector, context){
    if(!context || !context.querySelectorAll) context = document;
    return Array.from( context.querySelectorAll( selector ) );
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
    if(!checkClass(event.target, '.dropbtn')){
        $$('.dropdown-content.show').forEach(function(el){
            el.classList.remove('show');
        });
    }
}
```

or let's go even a bit further (#ES6, #FP):

```
//more utils:
var traverseUp = el => {
    for(var result = []; el; el = el.parentElement) result.push( el );
    return result;
}
var hasClass = cls => el => el.classList.contains(cls);
var addClass = cls => el => el.classList.add(cls);
var removeClass = cls => el => el.classList.remove(cls);

window.onclick = function(event) {
    if( !traverseUp(event.target).some( hasClass('.dropbtn') ) ) 
        $$('.dropdown-content.show').forEach( removeClass('show') );
}
```